# Git: distinguish between local and remote tags

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

If there are tags in the remote repository, I'm usually getting them automatically when pulling. When I delete the created local tag (`git tag -d <tag-name>`) and pull, the deleted tag will be recreated. I can delete remote branches/tags (`git push <remote-branch/tag-name>:<branch/tag-name>`), but how can I **detect that the local tag was created by fetching a remote tag**?

Comment: If you're in a friendly place, the tags would be annotaed, and the ones you've fetched from elsewhere would generally have authors that aren't you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're annoyed about these tags being recreated when you run `git pull`, you turn off the fetching of tags by default with the [remote.<remote-name>.tagopt](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#_options_related_to_fetching) config setting.  e.g. if the remote is `origin`, then you can do:

```
git config remote.origin.tagopt --no-tags
```

*Update:* to address your comment, the reason that I suggest this is that there's not an obvious way to tell the difference between a tag that was created locally and one that was fetched from a remote.  There's also no `reflog` for tags.  So, my suggestion is to suppress automatic fetching of tags - you can then fetch them yourself into a different namespace. For example, you could do:

```
git fetch origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/origin/*
```

... and perhaps create an alias for that.  Then when you want to fetch tags, they'll be named, for example, `refs/tags/origin/tag1` instead of `refs/tags/tag1`.

---

If you want this to happen automatically, you could change your `.git/config` to list multiple refspecs for fetching, e.g.:

```
 [remote "origin"]
      url = whoever@whereever:whatever.git
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
      fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/origin/*
```

... which is [suggested in Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Comment: I don't want to turn off fetching tags, I want to detect whether a locally available tag was created by fetching or manually.

Comment: @mklhmnn: my idea was that you can suppress automatic fetching of tags, and then when you want the remote tags, fetch them into a different namespace.  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @Mark: I find the approach much to the point than mine, separating tags by namespace on fetch. I would +1, but I already did before your edit ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply create local tags in a different namespace.

Comment: Thanks, Mark and VonC. So the answer is: no, one can't distinguish between locally created tags and tags created from a remote, isn't it?

Comment: Is there a way to add that fetch line in your .git/config without manually editing the .git/config file? I'm looking for something like "git remote set-branches --add ..." but it always prepends refs/heads. Also, the Pro Git book doesn't seem to mention tags at all in the page you link... it would've been probably better to also quote the relevant bit at the time :)

Comment: `git tag -l | xargs git tag -d` to delete all local tags, followed by `git fetch origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` (without `origin/`) worked for me to restore the original state (I wanted to remove tags I added locally).

Answer (score 10):

a tag isn't "local" or "remote": it is associated to a commit, which can part of multiple branches, including ones in the remotes namespace.

Get tag SHA1 of the commit referenced by a tag

```
git show -s 'TAG_NAME^{commit}' --format='%H'
```

, and do a :

```
git branch -a --contains SHA1
```

If you see

```
 remotes/aRemoteRepoName/aBranch
```

you know that tag references a commit you have fetched from a remote repo.

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen) mentions:

```
git branch -a --contains TAGNAME
```

will dereference the tag and gives the answer in one go.

Comment: Why not all in one command: `git branch -a --contains 'TAG_NAME^{commit}`?

Comment: Thinking about it some more, `--contains` will automatically dereference the named object, so there is no need to manually specify the dereferencing either. Simply `git branch -a --contains TAG_NAME` works as expected.

Comment: I don't want to know whether a tag is located in the history of a branch, I want to know whether the tag was created by fetch or manually.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, which answers the question.  Thank you.  (I agree with @Mot, I don't want to know about history, I want to know whether the tag was created locally or whether it was pulled from the remote.  So without semi-destructive solutions like deleting all tags and re-fetching, there is no way.)

Answer (score 3):

As long as you currently have access to the remote repository, you can compare the results of

```
git ls-remote --tags
```

with

```
git show-ref --tags -d
```

Note:

- The remote must currently be available
- If the tag was deleted from the remote, you wouldn't be able to tell that the "local" tag was originally pulled from the remote
- This will allow you to see when the remote and local have the same tag name but either reference different commits or were created/updated independently (for annotated tags, the tag hashes would be different even if the commit hash was the same)